# convert json String to array java object by Gson

Tags: json, arraylist, gson

I never understand that how can I use gson.
this is my json string that is fetched from my web service:

```
{
"GetHistoricalNotificationsInTopicByFilterResult":[
  {
     "BusinessCode":"10-1-75-16-1-3-0",
     "CreationDateTime":"\/Date(1502550561602)\/",
     "DeviceId":"8998432005",
     "Distributions":null,
     "EventData":[ ],
     "EventId":"com.test.revisit.events",
     "EventTitle":"sending",
     "Id":"69dbc367-09ws-bf3c-9re8-5c6b35ecbrtg",
     "ProcessId":"4ebb6271-bf3c-9re8-a148-5c6b35ec458",
     "SystemId":"com.safarayaneh.revisit",
     "SystemTitle":"seeing",
     "UserFullName":"jack",
     "UserId":"69dbc367-32f3-4e94-bf3c-5c6b35ec3456",
     "WKT":"POLYGON ((59.0 36.0, 59.01 36.01, ...))",
     "WorkItemId":2354365
 },{
 ....
}
```

and this is my contract class:

```
public class SaveNotify implements Parcelable {

private long id;
private String NotificationID;
private String MessageID;
private String CreationDateTime;
private String DeviceId;
private String UserId;
private String UserFullName;
private String SystemId;
private String SystemTitle;
private String EventId;
private String EventTitle;
private String EventData;
private String BusinessCode;
private String ProcessId;
private String WorkItemId;
private String WKT;
private String Distributions;
private String Address;
private String SaveDate;
private String Status;
private String DistributionId;
private String SchedulerCreationDateTime;
private String ExpirationDateTime;
```

how can I convert json string that i receive from my webservice to pojo class as array list?  I want to put this list to my recycler view adapter for showing this info as a list.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to create is an object that gets the field `GetHistoricalNotificationsInTopicByFilterResult`

```
public class MainObject implements Parceable{

    List<SaveNotify > GetHistoricalNotificationsInTopicByFilterResult;

}
```

And then, with Gson parce you JSON to The MainObject

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MainObject mainObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MainObject.class);
```

Comment: I add your suggestion to my pojo class and then I add this comment:      `Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<List<SaveNotify>>>() {}.getType();
            List<SaveNotify> yourList = gson.fromJson(response, type);` but I got this error `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`

Comment: List<SaveNotify> yourList = gson.fromJson(response, type); this is wrong. THis is not what i told you to do

Comment: You need to do exactly what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: `MainObject mainObject` is a list but your comment is not!I received that from AsyncTask. http://codepad.org/VJ0nrZqf

Comment: You JSON is OVERALL an object, thats why you need an obect, after that you need to check what comes next, that is GetHistoricalNotificationsInTopicByFilterResult, which is a list, so you put a list inside that object. Since it is a list, you need an object for each element of the list, this is your SaveNotify.  in `gsonFromJson you get a MainObject, not a List<SaveNotify>